# Comparison of objects always returns default select case

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I aim to pass 2 states into the following function and have it determine whether the states are identical, or are neighbors. If they are, I want the function to return true, and if not, false.

```
function shouldWeRun(origin, destination) {

  var shouldWeRun = false;

  switch (origin) {
    case destination:
      shouldWeRun = true;
    case "Massachusetts":
      if ( destination == "Connecticut" ||
           destination == "New Hampshire" ||
           destination == "New York" ||
           destination == "Rhode Island" ||
           destination == "Vermont" ) { shouldWeRun = true; };
           break;
    default:
      shouldWeRun = false;
  };

  return shouldWeRun;

};
```

When I declare states as an array of strings, like this...

```
var states = ["Massachusetts","Massachusetts","Connecticut","Virginia"];
```

...and run this:

```
Logger.log("same state should return true: " + shouldWeRun(states[0],states[1]));
Logger.log("state neighbors should return true: " + shouldWeRun(states[0],states[2]));
Logger.log("non-neighbor states should return false: " + shouldWeRun(states[0],states[3]));
```

...the function works as advertised.

However, here's the problem: if I instead get the states values from the spreadsheet (how I need to) like this...

```
var states = sheet.getRange("H2:H31").getValues();
```

...the function always returns the default case and therefore, false.

Assume that every cell in the range H2:H31 is "Massachusetts".

Comment: When you debug your script, and set a breakpoint in your `switch` statement, what do you notice about `origin` and `destination`?

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by `sheet.getRange("H2:H31").getValues()` is always a 2D array, ie an array of arrays, even when it is a single column.

You are comparing strings  with arrays, that's why the result is always `false`.

You should "flatten" that 2D array to get a simple one.
You can do this simply with a small code like this :

```
var states = sheet.getRange("H2:H31").getValues().join().split();
```